# A struct with an vector member c++

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I'm currently working on a simple problem, but I'm having an issue with getting an element from a vector inside a struct (I'm new to using struct). I know there error/exception is being called in the code snippet below. I just don't understand/see what would be causing this error/exception to be called. The error happens at `if (data[i].B[x] == str2))`. I know for a fact that str2 will always have a valid string in it. So, checking position 0 in the vector should be a valid call, but instead, I get "vector subscript out of range". I'm not sure if its something to do with how struct work (That I don't understand) or if I'm just not seeing something obvious. I just need a little push in the right direction to help me solve this issue. Any hints would be appreciated!

```
struct Things
{
    std::string A;
    std::vector <std::string> B;
};
```

```
    void fun(std::vector<Things> &data, std::string str2, std::string str1)
    { 
        bool dontAdd = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (data[i].A== str1)
            {
                if (data[i].B.size() == 0)
                {
                    data[i].B.push_back(str2);
                    dontAdd = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < data[i].B.size(); ++x)
                    {
                        std::cout << data[i].A;
                        std::cout << "The";
                        if (data[i].B[x] == str2)
                        {
                            dontAdd = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
       }
   }
```

```
std::string str2;
int countLoops = 0;
std::string str1;
std::vector<Things> data;
while (std::getline(dataFile, str2))
{
    if (countLoops == 0)
    {
        str1= str2;
        Afun(data, str2);
    }
    else if (countLoops == 1)
    {
        fun(data, str2, str1);
    }
    ++countLoops;

    if (str2.empty())
    {
        countLoops = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Can you show where you define `data`? Also, you say that `B` is filled with strings. Can you show where you fill it?

Comment: Now that you've included the function declaration, can you show how you call it?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.